# Prevent the run tool window from popping up everytime I run my tests

Tags: ide, tdd, intellij-idea

I run my tests a lot, most of the time all I need is the little balloon tip that pops up saying "12 tests passed" or "1 test failed".

That's all I need, but the run tab demands attention, and sometimes takes focus, which is very annoying when I'm typing.

I know I can hit escape when it takes focus, but I want to ignore the test results unless too many pass/fail.

So, is there anyway to bury the run window until I want to see the results, or run the test in the background (but not outside of the IDE)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there is no way to keep it completely hidden when running tests. Feel free to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).